# Верстка css button, как сверстать такую кнопку?

Tags: css

Как реализовать такую кнопку с нижним бордером под углом

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

у меня что то получилось, вот только по бокам как сделать, подскажите

```css
.button {
    display: inline-block;
    border: none;
    color: #fff;
    text-decoration: none;
    background-color: #ffb700;
    padding: 26px 45px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-weight: 600;
    letter-spacing: 3px;
    border-radius: 32px;
    text-align: center;
    position: relative;
    outline: 0;
    transition: background-color .1s ease;
}
.button::after {
    transition: background-color .2s ease;
    position: absolute;
    content: '';
    height: 4px;
    bottom: 0;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: #5f4004;
    opacity: .18;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 2px;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 2px;
    left: 0;
}

.button:active::after {
    opacity: .32;
}

.button:hover::after {
    opacity: .22;
}

.button:hover {
    background-color: #fea60d;
}
```

```html
<a href="" class="button">Бесплатный расчет </a>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Это делается с помощью внутренней тени. Цвет уже под себя настраивайте

```css
.button {
    display: inline-block;
    border: none;
    color: #fff;
    text-decoration: none;
    background-color: #ffb700;
    padding: 26px 45px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-weight: 600;
    letter-spacing: 3px;
    border-radius: 32px;
    text-align: center;
    position: relative;
    outline: 0;
    transition: background-color .1s ease;
    box-shadow: inset 0 -5px 0 0 #aaa; /* тень */
}

.button:hover {
    background-color: #fea60d;
}
```

```html
<a href="" class="button">Бесплатный расчет </a>
```